# Sequelize with node.js(typescript)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js

Can we use sequelize with aws lambda to connect with database(sqlserver) as in almost all the toturial its being used with js file not with typescript file .
Any example to use it in lambda function which is used as api

Comment: ts is a superset of js so just follow the js example and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a superset of Javascript, you can do the same things in that example, it will work.

Here is a Example of Lamba with Typescript:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/another-possibility-typescript-aws-lambda-ruwan-geeganage/